# EF Core & ASP.NET Core MVC add new data instead update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to update some content and my codes just adding new row instead updating data. I am already using addscoped in startup.cs. (Previous answers were about this.)
I am using repository pattern.
For the answer i take previously ; OF COURSE i have database and all the parts i need. I am doing insert, delete without problem.

Here is my entity:

```
public class Product : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Name can not be empty.")]
    [MinLength(3,ErrorMessage ="Lenght must be at least 3 characters.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double? Discount { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Image URL")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; } = true;

    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my repo. for updating :

```
public async Task<int> Update(Product entity)
{
       
    entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;           
    dbContext.Update(entity);
    return await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Here is the controller : DD methods for view. Showing category/team names instead their id on dropdowns.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ProductUpdateRequest productToUpdate)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            
        int affectedRows= await productService.UpdateProduct(productToUpdate);

        if (affectedRows>0)
        {
            TempData["RowAlert"] = "Edit successfully performed.";
        }
           
        return View();

    }
    TempData["RowAlert"] = "Your entries are not acceptable. Check your properties.";
    List<SelectListItem> selectedCategories = new List<SelectListItem>();
    selectedCategories = await getCategoriesforDD();

    List<SelectListItem> selectedTeams = new List<SelectListItem>();
    selectedTeams = await getTeamsforDD();

    ViewBag.Categories = selectedCategories;
    ViewBag.Teams = selectedTeams;

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you want.... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding an ID to my DTO. (Primary key of the entity.)

```
public class ProductUpdateRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ürün adı boş bırakılamaz.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double? Discount { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }     
    public int? TeamId { get; set; }     
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As by your previous comment, this should work:

```
public async Task<int> Add(Product entity)
{
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
    return await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/entity-state

Comment: I tried again and that exception thrown. Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Comment: What's the value of the primary key before you add it?

Comment: I solved my problem. I really appreciate for your affort. I did not add Primary Key to my DTO( ProductUpdateRequest).  I remembered because of you thanks :-)

Comment: Good to hear you solved it : ) Do note that "thanks" is expressed by upvoting and/or accepting the andwer. I you think this did not answer your question, you can also answer your own question and mark it as answer. This helps the people putting time in this and others when they have similar problems.